# .htaccess redirect QUERY_STRING and not propage QUERY_STRING

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I would like to make a permanent redirection of

```
/ask?search%255Bto%255D=test
```

to

```
/question/test
```

I add in my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search%255Bto%255D=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)
RewriteRule ^ask$ /question/%1 [R=permanent,L]
```

With these additional lines, I get

```
/ask?search%255Bto%255D=test
```

redirect to

```
/question/test?search%255Bto%255D=test
```

My problem is than I still have the query string (?search%255Bto%255D=test) in my redirection url.

I would like to have:

```
/question/test
```

and not

```
/question/test?search%255Bto%255D=test
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear the query string, simply end your target URL with a question mark. Try changing your rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^ask$ /question/%1? [R=permanent,L]
```

This specifies a new, empty query string, so the old one will not be sent as part of the redirect URL.